# How to Parse Databound Items in ListView Item Template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm very new to programming using Visual Studio. I have a query that pulls an unknown number of records into a ListView item template. The returned results contain a Price field `<%# Item.Price %>`, which is a string of prices separated by a semicolon. I've bound `<%# Item.Price %>` to a hidden Label:

`<asp:Label ID="ItemPrice" runat="server" visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>'></asp:Label>`

I want to parse and the sum this field and then display it in the same item template for each of the rerturned rows.

```
<%
int index = 0;
Label PriceLabel = ListView.Items[index].FindControl("Price") as Label;
                          
string[] strPrice = PriceLabel.Text.Split(';');
                            
int[] TotalPrice = strPrice.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
                            
int sumTotal = TotalPrice.Sum();%>

<%= sumTotal %>
```

The result is that all items in the item template have the same price based on `int index = x`.

Comment: ok, so you have say 200;300;400. Do you want to split out each value in the ONE row, or you do you want multiple extra rows for each split value? (and hit the person that has such un-normalized data!). So, do you want to say take first two values and display in two extra columns, or do you want a extra row for each delimited value? What you need here will determine the solution that makes sense here.

Comment: Ah, ok, it looks like you want the 1-N values, and to display the SUM() of those multiple values for the one row. Ok then!

Comment: Thank you for responding Albert! I've hit myself :) I may be going about this the wrong way; I want it to give me 900 (200+300+400). I've built something similar to a new car option builder, where each option category has (query returns) 2 - 14 available options. The price for each option may be 200 or 200;300 or 200;300;400;500. I need to sum the total of the ; separated price field for each record returned in the item template of a listview.

Comment: Ok, see my post below - I show how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so say we have this markup:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="PriceOptionsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PriceOptions") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="RoomCost" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class="table table-bordered">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">ID</th>
                    <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                    <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                    <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                    <th runat="server">Description</th>
                    <th runat="server">PriceOptions</th>
                    <th runat="server">Room Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

We will REMOVE the pricing field (that delimited field).

There are two ways to do this.

Most common for formatting, highlight of each row for colors etc? we will use the data bound event.

But, we have a Price column in above - just not bound without a data source.

So, now our code to fill out above:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels Order by HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                    DataTable rst = new DataTable();
                    rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                    ListView1.DataSource = rst;
                    ListView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok, so now we have this:

[image]

So, as noted, we will use the row bound event.

so, we do this:

```
    protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            // get the data row and NOT the Price options from the grid, since we
            // plan to remove that column!! we do NOT thus use FindControl as we 
            // would in most casess
            DataRowView rRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

            string[] PriceList = rRow["PriceOptions"].ToString().Split(';');
            decimal PriceSum = 0;
            foreach (string sAmount in PriceList){
                PriceSum += Convert.ToDecimal(sAmount);
            }

            // now put sum into Room cost
            Label RoomCost = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("RoomCost");
            RoomCost.Text = PriceSum.ToString("C2"); 
        }
    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

And thus we now free to remove the one PriceOptions "row" from above td, and template, and thus we now have this:

[image]

In a few minutes, I'll post a 2nd way.

ok, the other way to do this? And sometimes this is better, if you going to persist the data table. You can modify the table AFTER you load it.

So, say like this:

```
   void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE PriceOptions is not null Order by HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                    DataTable rst = new DataTable();
                    rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                // add full name column
                DataColumn fullName = rst.Columns.Add("FullName");
                fullName.Expression = "FirstName + LastName";

                DataColumn RoomCost = rst.Columns.Add("RoomCost", typeof(decimal));

                foreach (DataRow rRow in rst.Rows)
                {
                    string[] PriceList = rRow["PriceOptions"].ToString().Split(';');
                    decimal PriceSum = 0;
                    foreach (string sAmount in PriceList)
                        PriceSum += Convert.ToDecimal(sAmount);

                    rRow["RoomCost"] = PriceSum;
                }

                ListView1.DataSource = rst;
                ListView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

So FEW realize that you can EVEN add "expressions" to the table. So I made up a new table column of FullName, and note how I do not have to process that data - it is a expression based on two other columns.

This can often save you having to change the SQL or stored procedure that fills the table.

So, now our markup becomes even less like this:

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:Label ID="FullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="RoomCost" runat="server" width="120px" 
                    Text='<%# String.Format("{0:C2}",Eval("RoomCost")) %>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class="table table-bordered">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">Name</th>
                    <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                    <th runat="server">Description</th>
                    <th runat="server" >Room Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

So we dump the data bound event code - we on't need it anymore.

And we now have this:
[image]